# Expression Expected window.Laravel.userId = <?php in PHPstorm

Tags: laravel, vue.js, expression, phpstorm

I am building an app using Laravel, Vuejs and editor 'PHPstorm'

I wrote following code in my **app.blade.php** file inside **`<head></head>`** tag

> ```
> @if(!auth()->guest())
>         <script type="text/ecmascript-6">
>             window.Laravel.userId = <?php echo auth()->user()->id; ?>
>         </script>
>     @endif
>
>
> </head>
> <body>
> ```

it is showing 'expression expected' error in phpstorm.
[image]
what is the solution for that?

(note new updations of my question)
then My next question is that I want to use this in my **app.js** file

> console.log(window.Laravel.userId)
>
> if(window.Laravel.userId){

is the above code is the right way to use it in .js file or there is a better solution??

### (new update) My code

Here I add my code
**app.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">


    <script type="text/ecmascript-6">
        window.Laravel = '<?php echo json_encode([
                'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
        ]); ?>'
    </script>

@if(!auth()->guest())
        <script>
            window.Laravel.userId = '<?php echo auth()->user()->id; ?>'

         </script>
     @endif


 </head>
 <body>
     <div id="app">
         <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
             <div class="container">
                 <div class="navbar-header">

                     <!-- Collapsed Hamburger -->
                     <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#app-navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                         <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                     </button>

                     <!-- Branding Image -->
                     <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                        {{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="app-navbar-collapse">
                    <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        &nbsp;
                    </ul>

                    <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">


                        {{--add code here extra for notification--}}
                        @if(Auth::check())
                            <lesson v-bind:lessons="lessons"></lesson>
                        @endif




                    <!-- Authentication Links -->
                        @guest
                            <li><a href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{{ route('register') }}">Register</a></li>
                        @else
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true">
                                    {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>

                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                            onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                            Logout
                                        </a>

                                        <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                                        </form>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        @endguest
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        @yield('content')
    </div>

    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```js
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

window._=require('lodash');
window.$=window.jQuery =require('jquery');


Vue.component('lesson', require('./components/LessonNotification.vue'));
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data:{
        lessons:''
    },
    created(){
       console.log(window.Laravel.userId);
        if(window.Laravel.userId){
            axios.post('/notification/lesson/notification').then(response => {
                this.lessons=response.data;
                console.log(response.data)
            });

            Echo.private('App.User.'+window.Laravel.userId).notification((response) =>{
                data={"data":response};
                this.lessons.push(data);
            });

        }
    }

});
```

### The main task of code

Actually, My code's main theme or task is that I want to use or get the **logged-in** user information in any scripts specially **.js** file. That's why First I set up or define logged user info .. the following code in app.blade.php

> @if(!auth()->guest())
>           
>               window.Laravel.userId = user()->id; ?>
>           
>       @endif

Then since I need **logged-in** user id .so I called it by the following code in **app.js**

> console.log(window.Laravel.userId)

### My answer from @vivek_23

```
<script type="text/ecmascript">
        window.Laravel = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode([
                'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
        ]); ?>');
    </script>

<!-- This makes the current user's id available in javascript -->

    @if(!auth()->guest())
        <script>
            window.Laravel.userId = '<?php echo auth()->user()->id; ?>'
        </script>
    @endif
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add single quotes in your expression or I would suggest you to better use interpolation `{{}}` which Laravel blade syntax provides.

```
<script type="text/ecmascript-6">
            window.Laravel = {{ json_encode(['csrf_token' => csrf_token()]) }};
</script>

@if(!auth()->guest())
        <script type="text/ecmascript-6">
            window.Laravel.userId = {{ auth()->user()->id }};
        </script>
@endif
```

**#Update:**

```
<script type="text/ecmascript-6">
        window.Laravel = '<?php echo json_encode([
                'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
        ]); ?>'
</script>
```

Your code above has a string(JSON string) in `window.Laravel` and not a JSON object. You could do an additional [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to make it a JSON object as below.

```
<script type="text/ecmascript">
        window.Laravel = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode([
                'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
        ]); ?>');
</script>
```

Now, you are trying to get logged-in user ID.

```
<script>
        window.Laravel.userId = '<?php echo auth()->user()->id; ?>'
</script>
```

This code above would work as is because we have fixed type of `window.Laravel` from `JSON string` to `object`.

But best is to keep it as integer/number itself.

```
<script>
      window.Laravel.userId = <?php echo auth()->user()->id; ?>;
</script>
```

**Suggestion:**

Since you are using Laravel framework, it's better to always go with Laravel blade syntax than dealing with PHP tags. So, it would change your code snippets as below:

```
<script type="text/ecmascript">
        window.Laravel = {!! json_encode(['csrfToken' => csrf_token()]) !!};
</script>

<script>
      window.Laravel.userId = {{ auth()->user()->id }};
</script>
```

Notice the use of `{!! !!}` instead of `{{ }}`. This is because when you use normal interpolation, Laravel automatically escapes string content to prevent XSS attacks by passing it via [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php). We need to use `{{}}` if we are trying to print any user supplied information. In your case, you are generating a csrf token and sending token to client side. Hence, it is safe to print data unescaped.

More information is [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#displaying-data).

Since Laravel `5.5`, we can directly use the `@json` blade directive.

```
<script type="text/ecmascript">
        window.Laravel = @json([
                'csrfToken' => csrf_token()
        ]);
</script>
```

Comment: vivek_23 it is right inside <body></body> tag...but i wrote code inside <head></head> tag..your code is not running inside <head> tag

Comment: @Borna `head` or `body` tag shouldn't make a difference. Can you show your code so that I could check?

Comment: I already add my code in my question. please check. maybe head or body tag shouldn't make a difference...but your code run in body tag not in head tag

Comment: @Borna what's the error you are getting when doing the console.log?

Comment: @Borna can you share a proper full code so that I could debug better?

Comment: when doing the console.log,  it inputs 'undefined'...that case I used inside <head> tag @if(!auth()->guest())
        <script>
            window.Laravel.userId = '<?php echo auth()->user()->id; ?>'

         </script>
     @endif

Comment: @Borna Ok, but can you share one full code snippet?

Comment: Thanks @vivek_23 ...your suggestion part is working for me...thanks again take a time for answering my question

Answer (score 1):

Put your statement in the quotes like this

```
window.Laravel.userId = "<?php echo auth()->user()->id; ?>"
```

i just tested this and its working
Kindly try this

Comment: what statement...can you answer broadly??

Comment: yes it's working correctly...but when I try to use it in my .js file..it gives that it's undefined..can you go through my question again?. I updated my question. Thanks

Comment: Ok. I will check and revert

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [blade syntax to display variables](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#displaying-data) in views:

```
@if(!auth()->guest())
    <script type="text/ecmascript-6">
        window.Laravel.userId = {{ auth()->user()->id }};
    </script>
@endif
```